# creating a new variable out of two variables in function

Tags: javascript

.JS code:

```
const allButtonsToStore = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
let countingNewVariables = 0;
for (x=0; x < allButtonsToStore.length; x++) {
  allButtonsToStore[x].addEventListener("click", function(){
    let reason[countingNewVariables] = allButtonsToStore[x].innerHTML;
    console.log(reason[countingNewVariables]);
    countingNewVariables++;
  });
}
```

My question starts at `let reason[countingNewVariables]`. I want it to create a new variable for each button ar following: reason0, reason1, reason2, etc.

example above does not work. I've also tried `let reason[countingNewVariables]` and `let (reason + countingNewVariables)`

My question here is how do I let it create a new variable every time, where the name of the variable = `reason + countingNewVariables`

Edit after suggestion:

```
const allButtonsToStore = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
let reason = [];
for (x=0; x < allButtonsToStore.length; x++) {
  allButtonsToStore[x].addEventListener("click", function(){
    reason[x] = this.textContent;
    console.log(reason[x]);
  });
}
```

Comment: No, you do *not* want to create a new variable for each button. Believe you me. You may want an *array* of buttons, or an *object* of buttons. But you certainly don't want *variable variables.*

Comment: What you can do is declare the `reason` above your foorloop as an array (or object - depends on your usage). `let reason = []; for (x=0; x < allButtonsToStore.length; x++) { reason[x] = 'whatever' }`

now you can access the reason

Comment: @IamL Thanks! Only It's always outputting reason20 (I do have 20 buttons but reason1 does not exist for example)

Comment: @number42 it you should access it as an array like `reason[1]` or `reason[20]`

Comment: @IamL I'm afraid still not. I think I'm doing something wrong. I've entered a new block of code and adjusted according to your suggestion. Maybe you will notice what I'm doing wrong? It's giving me undefined  when I console log reason[0] in chrome. The console log in the javascript is working tho

Comment: @number42 hmmm seems to be correct - can you try logging reason after the for loop and see what it contains?

Comment: It's also undefined unfortunately

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207178/discussion-between-number42-and-i-am-l).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/476…